# Is there the equivalent of the stepAIC function for PERMANOVA?

Tags: r, permutation-test, stepwise-regression

I am comparing the presence and abundance of species between different sites, which are different in more than 1 factor, and the factors are not independent. I am looking to get the relative contribution of each factor to explain the variation between the sites.

I use the function adonis to perform a PERMANOVA but I have noticed that the p-value of a factor decreases (= its significance increases) when: (a) I remove other factors from the formula, (b) the earliest in the formula (first to last), (c) if I modify the number of permutations (increase the number of permutations increases the significance of the 1st factors in the formula, and decreases the significance of the later factors).

Is there the equivalent of a stepAIC function or any other way to make R (1) test all the possible combinations of formulas given all the factors, and (2) give me which of them predicts the variation the best?